# Calculating Big-O Runtime

Tags: c++, time-complexity, big-o, code-analysis

I'm in dire need of some guidance with calculating Big-O runtime for the following C++ function:

```
Fraction Polynomial::solve(const Fraction& x) const{
    Fraction rc;
    auto it=poly_.begin();
    while(it!=poly_.end()){
        Term t=*it;
        //find x^exp
        Fraction curr(1,1);
        for(int i=0;i<t.exponent_;i++){
            curr=curr*x;
        }
        rc+=t.coefficient_*curr;
        it++;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

This is still a new concept to me, so I'm having a bit of trouble with getting it right. I'm assuming that there are at least two operations that happen once (auto it = poly_.begin, and the return rc at the end), but I am not sure how to count the number of operations with the while loop. According to my professor, the correct runtime is not O(n). If anyone could offer any guidance, it would be greatly appreciated. I want to understand how to answer this question, but I couldn't find anything else like this function online, so here I am. Thank you.

Comment: You have a loop within a loop.  What does that suggest to you?

Comment: Try solving simpler sub problems first. For example, what would the runtime be without the inner for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to evaluate a certain polynomial (let us say `A_n*X^n + ... + A_0`) in a given point (rational value since it is given as a Fraction).

The first `while` loop will iterate through all the individual components of your polynomial. For an n-degree polynomial, that will yield `n + 1` iterations, so the outer loop alone takes O(n) time.
However, for every term (let us say of rank `i`)of the polynomial, you have to compute the value of `X^i`, and that is what your inner `for` loop does. It computes `X^i` using a linear method, yielding linear complexity: O(i).

Since you have two nested loops the overall complexity is obtained by multiplying the worst-case time complexities of the loops. The resulting complexity is given by O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2). (First term indicates the complexity of the `while` loop, while the second one indicates the worst-case time complexity for computing `X^i`, which is O(n) when `i == n`).

Comment: Thank you @Polb, even with my limited knowledge in this subject, I was able to go through the function with your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a n-order polynomial (highest term is raised to the power of n).

In the outer while loop, you will iterate through n+1 terms (0 to n inclusive on both side).

For each term, in the inner for loop, you are going to perform multiplication m times whereby m is the power of current term. Since this is a n-order polynomial, m range from 0 to n. On average, you are going to perform multiplication n/2 times.

The overall complexity will be O((n+1) * (n/2)) = O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @lamandy. This may be a dumb question, but how did you figure that on average, multiplication would be performed n/2 times? I didn't quite understand that part.

Comment: The lowest term is x^0, the highest term is x^n, the average multiplication required for these 2 terms are n/2. Similarly, pair x^1 with x^(n-1), x^2 with x^(n-2), etc. If you want a more formal explanation, 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n gives us (n^2 +n)/2, since there are (n+1) terms, we get n/2 multiplication on average. This is given considering the fact that the function does not skip multiplication when coefficient is 0 so the multiplication is still going to carry on even if it is just 0 * x = 0.

Comment: Considering that the question is asking for Big-O notation where we are looking for the upper bound, there is no point in considering skip 0 coefficient optimization as we should look for worst case scenario anyway. If your professor want to make this question more challenging, he can include that optimization and ask for Big O and Big Omega or even Big Theta notation.